# Detecting unsigned overflow when accumulating variables

Tags: c

I have two unsigned 32 bit integers, call them x and y. I want to periodically increment the two uint32's by seemingly random uint32 values. x and y will accumulate and I want them to continue to accumulate until they hit their limit, at which point I want them to start back at 0 + the value they would have had added had they not overflowed.

Assume the code looks like:

```
//This would be called, say every 5 seconds
void increment_vals(uint32_t *x, uint32_t *y, uint32_t x_inc, uint32_t y_inc)
{
    *x += x_inc;
    *y += y_inc;

    if (x overflowed || y overflowed)
    {
        *x = x_inc;
        *y = y_inc;
    }
}
```

So basically my question is: how do I know when x OR y has overflowed and need to to be reset? Should I just store x and y before incrementing and if the result is less than the original value then it must have overflowed? Is that guaranteed?

Thanks.

Comment: If `*x + x_inc` is less than `*x` then it's about to overflow.

Comment: c or c++ ? This is quite important.

Comment: @luk32 The language is C

Answer (score 1):

You could check for overflow before incrementing:

```
if(x_inc > (MAXINT - *x)) {
    //about to overflow
}
```

Comment: These values are unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
uint32_t xx = *x + x_inc;
if (xx < *x)
     *x = 0;
else *x = xx;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this document](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321335724/samplechapter/seacord_ch05.pdf) quite helpful and descriptive in answering my question, particularly page 172:

"For unsigned integers, if the sum is smaller than either operand,
an overflow has occurred."